# How to live stream video using C program. What should be the HTTP reply ? How can I use chunked encoding if possible?

Tags: c, http, streaming, video-streaming, live-streaming

(the actual question has been edited because I was successful doing live streaming, BUT NOW I DO NOT UNDERSTAND THE COMMUNICATION between client and my C code.)

Okay I finally did live streaming using my C code. BUT I COULD NOT UNDERSTAND HOW "HTTP" IS WORKING HERE.
I studied the communication b/w my browser and the server at the link http://www.flumotion.com/demosite/webm/ using wireshark.

I found that the client first sends this GET request

```
GET /ahiasfhsasfsafsgfg.webm HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: file:///home/anirudh/Desktop/anitom.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/9.0.597.98 Safari/534.13
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Range: bytes=0-1024
```

to this get request the server responds by sending this reply

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Tue, 01 Mar 2011 06:14:58 GMT
Connection: close
Cache-control: private
Content-type: video/webm
Server: FlumotionHTTPServer/0.7.0.1
```

and then the server sends the data until the client disconnects. The client disconnects when it receives a certain amount of data. The CLIENT then connects to the server on a new port and the same GET request is sent to the server. The server again gives the same reply but this time the client does not disconnect but continuously reads the packets until the server disconnects. I wrote a C code which in which I have a server socket which replicates the above behavior. (thanks to wireshark, flumotion and stackoverflow)

BUT BUT BUT, I could not understand why does the client need to send two requests and why does it resets on the first request and again send the same request on a new port and this time it listens to the data as if its getting live streamed.
Also I do not know how I can live stream using chunked encoding.

The same thing in detail is available here : http://systemsdaemon.blogspot.com/2011/03/live-streaming-video-tutorial-for.html

and here http://systemsdaemon.blogspot.com/2011/03/http-streaming-video-using-program-in-c.html

Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first request is limited to 1024 bytes in order to test that the stream is actually a valid video source and not say a 600MB Windows executable.